# Finding a formula using two other functions.

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I am trying to find a formula for $p(x)$, but I am not seeing where to start.

I have two functions  $m(x)=9*27^x$ and $n(x)=9^x$

I need to find the formula for function $p(x)$ if $m(x) = p(n(x))$

I'm sure it is something simple I just can't get it to click.. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: My thoughts. Note $27 = 3 \times 9$, so $m(x) = 3^x \cdot 9^{x + 1} = 3^{3x + 2}$.  Now $p(9^x) = p(3^{2x}) = 3^{3x + 2}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(x)=9 \cdot 27^{\ln x/\ln 9}$.

Then $p(n(x))=p(9^x)=9 \cdot 27^{ln 9^x/\ln 9}=9 \cdot 27^{x\ln 9/\ln 9}=9 \cdot 27^x=m(x)$.